# jquery reload iframe after opening sliding panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, panel

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".trigger").click(function(){
        $(".shoutpanel").toggle("fast");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        return false;
    });
});
</script>

<a class="trigger" href="#">Shoutbox</a>


<div class="shoutpanel">
<iframe id="shoutbox" name="shoutbox" width="350" height="480" src="tchat.php">
</iframe>
</div>
```

This script will toggle a sliding panel with a shoutbox in it.
If i put the shoutbox outside of the sliding panel then it will automatically scroll down as soon as it is loaded (to display the last shout)
But for some unknown reason when i put the shoutbox inside the sliding panel, it won't scroll down unless i manually refresh it.

So i am trying to find a workaround and i thought about setting the trigger script to automatically refresh the shoutbox iframe when it is executed. So when you click the trigger it would refresh the shoutbox after opening the sliding panel

i'm not a jquery pro so i have not been able to do it myself... Basically i just need something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".trigger").click(function(){
    $(".shoutpanel").toggle("fast");
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    return false;
            document.getElementById(shoutbox).contentDocument.location.reload(true);
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of issues:

- You have a return false in your click event (which is not required) and also it is before your reload statement. So it never executes.
- document.getElementById(shoutbox) should have the id in quotes.
- With this you are always reloading the iframe even during slideUp.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".trigger").click(function () {
        $(".shoutpanel").toggle("fast", function () { //Use toggle's complete function 
            if ($(this).is(':visible')) {   // check if this is in visible mode
              document.getElementById("shoutbox")
                    .contentDocument.location.reload(true); //reload the iframe
            }
        });
        $(this).toggleClass("active");

    });
});
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3v5cc/)